# how to update the using unit of some values in many pages

Tags: design-patterns, xamarin.forms

I have three pages A,B,C, and each of them has a Label to show a different distance value and the distance values can be presented as Km or Mile. The app provides a settings page for the user to change the distance unit globally. My question is how to update the UI globally when the distance unit setting is changed?

My current solution is to let every page that has distance values subscribe to the unit changed event and update its UI element separately when the event is invoked, but the app will end up having many redundant codes in this way.

Is there any elegant solution to this issue?

**UPDATE**
The most important thing here is I want to update the distance value reactively when I change the using unit (something like re-trigger the value converter without manually assigning a new value to the distance binding). For example, I have multiple Labels {Binding Distance, Converter={DistanceConverter}}, each can bind to a different variable, but they all represent a distance. When I change the using unit in a modal view, all distance-related Labels should update their value automatically without refreshing the page.

Comment: Do you only support Km and Miles? Or do you plan to support more cultures(Try CultureInfo)? I have extended FreakyAli's answer by Resource way.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way of using this would be using Value Converters what you will do is maintain a global property in your `App.Xaml.cs` or somewhere of your choosing maintain it so that it does not lose its value using Application Properties or Essentials Preferences after doing that use the below convertor:

```
 public class KiloMeterMileConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       var isKiloMeter = parameter as bool;
       if(isKiloMeter){}
       else{}
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like

```
SomeProperty= {Binding ABinding, Converter={StaticResource KiloMeterMileConvertor }, ConverterParameter={Static local:YourIdentifier}}
```

Now you can use this in multiple ways to return which the current unit you are using or to convert the actual value.

If you do want to convert these value it is directly available in Xamarin.Essentials

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.unitconverters.kilometerstomiles?view=xamarin-essentials#Xamarin_Essentials_UnitConverters_KilometersToMiles_System_Double_

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.unitconverters.milestokilometers?view=xamarin-essentials#Xamarin_Essentials_UnitConverters_MilesToKilometers_System_Double_

Good luck

Feel free to get back if you have questions

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I also want to update the distance value reactively, not just the unit text. I have tried your solution, but it seems changing the value of ConverterParameter won't trigger the value update.

Comment: Your binding should be the thing that would be changing, so the change in the binding causes a property changed event!!

Comment: to say a label is binding to Distance, but I just want to change the using unit without changing the Distance value. So I am looking for a solution to achieve this goal.

Comment: So basically you want to change the unit and not the distance' s value?

Comment: From the UI perspective, I want to change both, but from the technical perspective, I want to trigger this UI change by changing the using unit setting only, without reassign a new value to Distance. Here is the scenario, a label is showing 100Km, a user clicks on the settings button, a popup shows up, sets the using unit to Miles, and then the label will change to 160Miles automatically. In the real project, there can be multiple distance-related ui elements across the app, so instead of using the code to reset their values one by one, I would like to know how to do it in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

The Resource way (Since you are searching for an elegant way, Extension of Freaky Ali's answer).

**App.Xaml**

```cs
    <Application.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="milesUnit">Miles</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="kmUnit">Km</x:String>
        <local:DistanceConverter x:Key="distanceConverter"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

**App.Xaml.cs**

```cs
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.Resources["distanceUnit"] = Application.Current.Resources["milesUnit"];
            ......
    }
```

**Converter**

```cs
    public class DistanceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string unit = Application.Current.Resources["distanceUnit"].ToString();
                double distance = double.Parse(value.ToString());
                if (unit == "Km")
                {
                    return distance * 1.60934;
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

**Page.Xaml**

```cs
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="In Page 1"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Distance,Converter={StaticResource distanceConverter}}"/>
        <Label Text="{DynamicResource distanceUnit}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

**Button Clicks**

```cs
    void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources["distanceUnit"] = Application.Current.Resources["milesUnit"];
    }

    void Button_Clicked_1(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources["distanceUnit"] = Application.Current.Resources["kmUnit"];
    }
```

If you are only going to support Miles and Km, alone Freaky Ali answer is great but if you are planning to support other cultures too try using [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks, but it seem your solution only updates the unit text, not the distance value. I want to also update the distance value when the using unit is changed reactively. Like the current distance is 100 in km, when I click ToMile button, the value will become 160. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No the second label has the value and is using the converter and it changes when you click the button. please do check.

Comment: Maybe I have missed something that I didn't notice... I basically just copy your code and the second label still won't update when I click the buttons, only the third label is updated. Here is my code: https://github.com/haoyuant/aaaaaa/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ohh.! The github page really helped. The button and label are in the same page. But the answers given were to change the data on other pages (converters are hit when the View is loaded / Binded data is changed). You mentioned there was a separate settings page where you change units. I'll try to alter the code to accommodated this scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much : ) Because in the real project, the settings page is a modal, changing the settings won't actually refresh or re-initiate the current page, so I want to change the distance value reactively instead of relying on the page's recreation.

Comment: You could use Messaging Center to send message at any class when button click .